# Firebase Rule - Match document to user via email address

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to get a simple rule to work: If a document from my `records` collection contains an email (`fatherEmail || motherEmail`) that matches the email of the user logging in, allow that doc to be read.  Not working - `Missing or insufficient permissions`.

Here are my rules:
[image: Cloud Firestore Rules]

Per Firebase tech support the recommended way to retrieve the auth'd user's email address:

`function getUserEmail(){
      return request.auth.token.email;
    }`

Here’s the Stackblitz: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/login-and-match-record-mvce?file=src%2Fapp%2Fauth.service.ts

Login using a verified email:
User: **devcore2911@gmail.com**
Pass: **foobar**
If you look at the console, you'll see the error I mentioned above.

My `records` collection contains one document that contains `devcore2911@gmail.com` as the value for the`fatherEmail` property so that doc *should* pull up:
[image: Matching Doc]

Answer (score 0):

The solution: I must perform a query to filter out the docs that match the user's email.

See this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/login-and-match-record-mvce?file=src%2Fapp%2Frecord-list%2Frecord-list.component.ts

Here's the code that solved the issue.  Note the use of `combineLatest` as Firebase queries do not support the `||` operator.

```
const matchFatherEmail = this.afs.collection("records", ref => ref.where("fatherEmail","==", this.authService.user.email));
const matchMotherEmail = this.afs.collection("records", ref => ref.where("motherEmail","==", this.authService.user.email));

this.records$ = combineLatest(matchFatherEmail.valueChanges(), matchMotherEmail.valueChanges())
  .pipe(switchMap(docs => {
    const [docsFatherEmail, docsMotherEmail] = docs;
    const combined = docsFatherEmail.concat(docsMotherEmail);
    return of(combined);
  }))
```